# Movable window that makes whatever under it inverted color

Tags: windows, video-editing, youtube

What if you had a window you could move around and could be resized that would invert the colors of whatever is underneath?

Example: Let's say you are reading a pdf closer to nighttime and you would prefer black background/white text

System: Windows 10 touchscreen laptop

Requirement: under 40$

Comment: Could you live with a solution that just does an invert for Youtube videos? You question text is ambiguous about that, your title suggests 'no', but Lucas has already given such a solution. Please [edit] your text.

Comment: In Windows 7, the default Magnifier app will do that.  Just enable "Turn on color inversion."  Did Microsoft leave that in for Windows 10, or did they remove that functionality?

Answer (score 2):

A long time ago I downloaded [MagicAction For Youtube](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/magic-actions-for-youtube/abjcfabbhafbcdfjoecdgepllmpfceif) (extension plug-in, just for chrome I think), you can do a lot of things like buffer for video (to help to load it), and also some crazy thing like revert the video screen, then you can also invert color:

[image]

Comment: Finding an other in 1 minut... just tipping "youtube invert color" --' and thanks for the -1, that's cool <3  : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-colors-filters/ojgmbbegpppllieiibjipgbpbnmonofi

Comment: Make that another answer ;-)

Comment: @JanDoggen I'm wondering if the invert text is noticeable enough:D